# Wrong Leaflet.js tiles position, snaps into place on drag

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, mapbox

I'm having trouble with a Leaflet bug (?) - when adding a layer, the tiles are in wrong position, and will only snap back into place on first drag. See [this animated gif.](http://noerd.biz/snap.gif)

The `map.invalidateSize()` does nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any code you can share? Or how you are adding your tile layer/overlays to the map

Answer (score 3):

I add some issue with ordering of maps when trying to add a map into a Modal

I managed to solved that with this command : 
    **L.Util.requestAnimFrame(map.invalidateSize, map, !1, map._container);**

Answer (score 2):

I've run across the same or similar bug on Webkit. (Firefox seems okay.)
I fixed it with this workaround. After it's rendered, call:

```
map.panBy([1, 0]);
```